# How do I install the "true" binary on MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I have a legacy Bash script which calls `/bin/true` somewhere.  When I run it on a MacOS system I get an error:

```
/bin/true: No such file or directory
```

How do I install `/bin/true` to the system? I couldn't find anything similar via `brew search`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in `/usr/bin` so change all references from `/bin/true` to `true` as it's reasonable to expect `/usr/bin` to be in the `$PATH`.

That or a load of tedious cross-platform conditional stuff...

Comment: This: the entire *point* of PATH lookup is to avoid non-portable hard-coded path names to common (if not standard) executables.

Comment: Right.. I checked `which true` but it gave me `true: shell built-in command`

Comment: @planetp Yeah it's built into some shells.  Even more reason not to specify an absolute path.

Comment: `which -a` will (often) show you *all* available paths, rather than just the first one. By the way, if `which true` told you it is a shell built-in, you would appear to be using `zsh`, not `bash`. `bash` doesn't have a built-in `which`, which means `which true` is running `/usr/bin/which`, which has no insight into what is or is not a shell built-in. `zsh`, on the other hand, *does* have a built-in `which`.